# Where does this code go?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, hopefully this will be my last question.  The code I have can be previewed working just fine over here: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/PT523/3/

So, when you type in na picture one changes, ma= the second one changes etc

But when I put it into my site, nothing happens. Could someone put it in the form of an HTML document/setup so I can see how it needs to be put together in order for it to work and display everything properly? Thank you so much!

Comment: My bad, I might have confused it with Vote Up privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAQ discourages, "here do this for me" questions.

This is a very basic illustration of where to put js. Remember, you won't have access to all the elements in the DOM, so you might want to use jquery's $(document).ready() or window.onload event.

```
<html><head><title>My Page</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    alert('Hello world');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:myFunction();">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap up your function inside a `$(document).ready()` event otherwise it won't work. It works in JSFiddle because it is set in the "onLoad" wrapper.